# Prevent Windows 8 Mail App from sending expired credentials

Tags: networking, windows-8, email, windows-8-mail-app

I have a MS Surface RT tablet which I've synced with my corporate email system. Over the weekend I saw that my password had expired, so I connected to the VPN from a desktop computer and changed it. I was almost immediately locked out of the network. So I spent Monday and Tuesday calling the helpdesk every hour or so to unlock my account, since my Surface which was quietly sitting on my nightstand and in my mind was "sleeping" was actively bombarding our corporate network with my expired credentials and locking out my account. So is there a way to configure the Win8 Mail APP to not retry cached credentials after a failed connection attempt? It seems to be to be a giant bug that it would continue to retry cached credentials after a failure, since this is a clear indication that the password has most likely changed and is no longer valid.

Comment: Configure the application to NOT remember your password or close the application every time your done with it. The application not any application can determine if your password expired and is not simply wrong

Comment: This is the Windows 8 "Metro" Mail app, it is always running as long as the computer is on. I don't have the Surface with me now but I don't believe there is a way to add an account without saving the password. Because of this issue I have removed my corp account but I'd add it back if I could figure out how to not retry stored credentials after a validation failure.

Comment: I am familiar with the application I use it daily it is possible to close the application.